# Долгое время добавления динамических элементов с#(winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть кнопка по нажатии которой добавляется около 10 элементов. При втором нажатии, то есть когда уже около 20 элементов всё добавляется очень долго и странная анимация.Как это исправить или сделать красивее?

Так выглядит один блок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот это происходит во время добавления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (с < 5)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label0 = new Label();
                    label0.Text = "Блок" + (с + 1).ToString();
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label0, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label = new Label();
                    label.Text = "memberId";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label5 = new Label();
                    label5.Text = "sourceId";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label5, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label6 = new Label();
                    label6.Text = "lastName";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label6, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label22 = new Label();
                    label22.Text = "middleName";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label22, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label8 = new Label();
                    label8.Text = "firstName";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label8, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label9 = new Label();
                    label9.Text = "landlineNumber";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label9, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label224 = new Label();
                    label224.Text = "mobileNumber";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label224, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label11 = new Label();
                    label11.Text = "email";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label11, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label12 = new Label();
                    label12.Text = "position";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label12, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    textBoxes2.Add(new TextBox());
                    textBoxes2[s].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(textBoxes2[s], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);//добавили на форму 
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 200));
                    s++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label13 = new Label();
                    label13.Text = "active";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label13, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    cCheckedLists1.Add(new cCheckedListBox());
                    cCheckedLists1[d].Items.AddRange(variants);
                    cCheckedLists1[d].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(298, 150);
                    cCheckedLists1[d].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(cCheckedLists1[d], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 170));
                    d++;
                    tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount++;
                    var label33 = new Label();
                    label33.Text = "category";
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label33, 0, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    cCheckedLists1.Add(new cCheckedListBox());
                    cCheckedLists1[d].Items.AddRange(variants);
                    cCheckedLists1[d].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(298, 150);
                    cCheckedLists1[d].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                    tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(cCheckedLists1[d], 1, tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount - 1);
                    d++;
                    с++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Соберите группы контролов в единый контрол при помощи UserControl и добавляйте за одну операцию. Сейчас у вас контрол перерисовывается после добавления каждого нового элемента. Ну или, хотя бы, "заморозьте" контейнер, в который вы все это добавляете на время изменения содержимого с помощью [Control.SuspendLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: с шарпом очень недавно, не слышал о usercontrol,гляну...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Легко и быстро это можно было исправить, как и написал rdorn. Вначале морозим контейнер  Control.SuspendLayout, а после всех действий размораживаем control.ResumeLayout();